# DB2 Logical Opeartion on Numeric column give different results when using single quote

Tags: java, db2, spring-jdbc

In DB2 database there is numeric column. We are using spring named jdbc template for DAO Operations.

The issue is when we use `numeric_column >= 'value'` it gives 100+ records but when we query  `numeric_column >= value` it give 50+ records. I am unable to understand this behavior.

So i need to know how this affect my result-set.

Comment: Don't compare apples (numbers) to oranges (strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without quotes, (`numeric_column >= value`), you are comparing numeric values, which is what I assume you meant to do. With quotes (`numeric_column >= 'value'`) will force both sides of the operator to be converted to strings, and then the values will be compare lexicographically.

Assume, for example, that the column contains the values `2`, `11` and `999`, and your value is `5`.
In a numeric comparison (`numeric_column >= 5`), you would get two rows returned - `11` and `999`. However, if you compare them lexicographically (`numeric_column >= '5'`), only one will be returned, `999`, as `5` is lexicographically later ("larger") than `11`.

Comment: Is this behavior db2 specific?

Comment: Ya in oracle it will treat both scenario as same.

Comment: With any RDBMS, when you compare a numeric value to a string value, some conversion takes place - either the string is converted to a number, or vice versa. As @SureshkumarPanneerselvan stated, Oracle implicitly converts strings to numbers in this usecase, but still, it's generally a bad practice. If you want to compare numbers - use numeric literals, not strings.

Comment: Yes @mureinik is correct. Its not standard, still we follow this since its a legacy system in which different system connected. So changing it to number involves many process and more level of approval.